# Printing Ifconfig with subprocess.check_output() gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

The name of file is Main.py

```
import subprocess

Interface = "eth0"
output1 = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", Interface])
```

when I try to execute above, I receive the following error.

```
/kunal/PycharmProjects/first/venv/bin/python /kunal/PycharmProjects/first/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/kunal/PycharmProjects/first/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    output1 = subprocess.check_output(["ifconfig", Interface])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifconfig'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The relevant part of the environment when running the program is :

```
HOME: /kunal
PATH: /kunal/PycharmProjects/first/venv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
PS1: (venv) 
PWD: /kunal/PycharmProjects/first
PYCHARM_HOSTED: 1
PYTHONIOENCODING: UTF-8
PYTHONPATH: /kunal/PycharmProjects/first
PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
SHELL: /bin/bash
USER: kunal
VIRTUAL_ENV: /kunal/PycharmProjects/first/venv
```

The 'env' path on shell is :

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

The result for "which ifconfig" :

```
/usr/sbin/ifconfig
```

Comment: I assume you have ifconfig.... is there something odd in the environment? Is there something wrong with PATH?

Comment: I am using pycharm on kali Linux that is all. I does execute when a command like 'ls' is used.

Comment: Try `print(os.environ)` in your program to see what pycharm is setting up. Compare to `env` on the command line. And try `which ifconfig` to see where ifconfig is on your systme.

Comment: can you please kindly check edits?, I am not good in this.

Comment: You posted `os.environ` twice, and not `echo $PATH` from the shell. But `os.environ` shows us that `/usr/sbin/` is not in the `PATH`, so it cannot be found when you execute it. Try just using the absolute path.

Comment: You are running in a virtual environment in pycharm and it doesn't include /sur/sbin. As mentioned you could hard code `/usr/sbin/ifconfig` and usually be right. Unfortunately I am not a pycharm expert and don't have the answer - but it would be worth looking at pycharm configs to see how you can fix this. Some OS's may put `ifconfig` in different places and if you want your code to work everywhere its worth sorting it out. Or hardcode!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Path was not present in `$PATH` variable.

`nano /etc/bash.bashrc`

Add `Export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin` As commands like ifconfig are there.